# Not created chromdriver session unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, selenide, webdrivermanager-java

Google Chrome v.110.0.5481.178
Selenide 6.12.0
webdrivermanager 5.3.2
Window 10
Java 19.2

When execute

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
Selenide.open("https://www.google.com");
```

I see this

```
Starting ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839}) on port 17120
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Test ignored.

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 

Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopb..., --disable-dev-shm-usage, --no-sandbox, --window-size=1366,768], excludeSwitches: [enable-automation, load-extension], extensions: [], prefs: {credentials_enable_service: false, download.default_directory: C:\Users\c-svetagey\Documen..., plugins.always_open_pdf_externally: true, profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads: 1, safebrowsing.enabled: true}}, pageLoadStrategy: normal, unhandledPromptBehavior: accept}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopb..., --disable-dev-shm-usage, --no-sandbox, --window-size=1366,768], excludeSwitches: [enable-automation, load-extension], extensions: [], prefs: {credentials_enable_service: false, download.default_directory: C:\Users\username\Documen..., plugins.always_open_pdf_externally: true, profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads: 1, safebrowsing.enabled: true}}, pageLoadStrategy: normal, unhandledPromptBehavior: accept}}]
selenide.url: https://www.google.com
selenide.baseUrl: http://localhost:8080
```

Also browser is open not in separate window at ingocnito mode, but at new tab of open browser with URL = data:,

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in chrome driver. Update to Selenide 6.12.2 fixed it.
Also there is a possible workaround.
Just add this line before opening a browser:

`System.setProperty("chromeoptions.args", "--remote-allow-origins=*");`